# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I loaded the iris dataset and transformed it into a matrix. It is then separated into training and test sets.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import metrics

# get all data
iris = load_iris()

def data():

    iris_data = iris.data

    # Transform data into a (samples, feature) matrix
    n_samples = len(iris_data)
    iris_data = iris.data.reshape((n_samples, -1))

    # Training and testing sets
    training_set, training_labels = iris_data[:n_samples // 2], iris.target[:n_samples // 2]
    testing_set, testing_labels = iris_data[n_samples // 2:], iris.target[n_samples // 2:]

    return (training_set, training_labels), (testing_set, testing_labels)
```

I then run Naive Bayes and Decision Tree classifiers.

```
def run_classifier(classifier, training, testing):

    classifier.fit(*training)

    expected = testing[1]
    predicted = classifier.predict(testing[0])

    return expected, predicted
```

Finally, I want to evaluate the classifier models.

```
def simulate():
    # progress through range of testing data sizes
    nb_acc = []
    tree_acc = []
    training_fracs = [x / 1000 for x in range(500, 850, 25)]

    for i in training_fracs:
        nb = GaussianNB()
        dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
        training, testing = data()

        nb_expect, nb_predict = run_classifier(nb, training, testing)
        dt_expect, dt_predict = run_classifier(dt, training, testing)

        nb_acc.append(metrics.accuracy_score(nb_expect, nb_predict))
        tree_acc.append(metrics.accuracy_score(dt_expect, dt_predict))

        training, testing = data

        nb_expect, nb_predict = run_classifier(nb, training, testing)
        dt_expect, dt_predict = run_classifier(dt, training, testing)

        nb_acc.append(metrics.accuracy_score(nb_expect, nb_predict))
        tree_acc.append(metrics.accuracy_score(dt_expect, dt_predict))

    return nb_acc, tree_acc, training_fracs


nb_acc_, tree_acc_, training_fracs_ = simulate(iris)

print(f"Naive Bayes accuracy @ 50% training: {nb_acc_[0]}")
print(f"Decision Tree accuracy @ 50% training: {tree_acc_[0]}")
```

Traceback error: cannot unpack non-iterable function object. What does it mean?

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\mod1.py", line 65, in
> <module>
>     nb_acc_, tree_acc_, training_fracs_ = simulate()   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\mod1.py", line 54, in
> simulate
>     training, testing = data TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object
```

Answer (score 4):

It means that you are trying to "unpack" a function reference as if it were a tuple, but it is only when you **call** the function that it returns a tuple. So you need to call your function, like this:

```py
training, testing = data()
```